# Any Open Source Games That Can Be Ported to Android?

Tags: c++, android, open-source

I'm looking for some other open source games out there that I can port (easily or not) to Android.  I know that it's possible to port Wolfenstein and Doom and was wondering if there are any others out there.  I was thinking of Civilization (I remember a linux port some time back) and a few others.  It can be in C/C++ or Java.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoever did the down vote, care to explain why?  A down vote helps me not.  You telling me I'm a newb and can find X stuff in Y place, does.

Comment: Just because the game code is open source doesn't mean you can release a port with the content.  The content (textures, sounds, levels, etc) is under copyright.  You'd have to look for a game that's completely open source, and those are pretty few and far between.

Comment: @Tetrad I don't think I said I wanted to release the game.  This is for learning purposes only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is probably [cube](http://cubeengine.com/cube.php4).  It uses the zlib license.  It's been ported to pretty small platforms so running on an android device isn't out of the question.

Comment: Sweet, Cube looks great.  I have something to play with now and maybe get some oohs and ahs.  I have to justify my late nights and evenings to the wife. ;)  I can't upvote but I'll accept this as answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Soshimo, you should really wait more than 4 hours before accepting an answer, as it kind of discourages more answers because anyone else posting **knows** that their answer will not be accepted.

Comment: @AttackingHobo Posting just to get an answer accepted kind of defeats the purpose of the site doesn't it?  Getting points seems kind of secondary to actually having people help others.  Maybe the point system is flawed if that's the only incentive to post.  I have a feeling that a lot of people don't share your sentiment.  Looking over your past comments it seems you have a definite agenda with accepting answers early since you seem to comment whenever you get a chance.  If I didn't know any better I would say it's a bot.

Comment: This conversation shouldn't be a part of this comment thread.  If you really want to discuss the merits of accepting answers, take it to meta.

Comment: Not meaning to butt-in here, but I agree with AttackingHobo on this point. 'Accepting' an answer is basically equivalent to saying 'I'm happy with this answer, I don't need any more' which is why questions giving a list rarely have accepted answers. EDIT: Ninja'd by Tetrad.

Comment: @AttackingHobo (and the rest) If that's the case then the developers of this website should turn off the auto notification that you have unanswered questions.  This being my first time here I just followed the suggestions of the notification.  Thanks for all the input though - tough crowd around here.